# How to fix "_existsIn' => 'This value does not exist'" Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.x

The function save only works when I remove the company_id but when I bring the company_id back the debug says "_existsIn' => 'This value does not exist'"

```
public function createForm(){
        $user = $this->Auth->user();
        $company_id = $user['company_id'];
        $form_title = $_POST['form_title'];
        $total_score = $_POST['total_score'];

        $form = $this->FieldCoachingForms->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $form->title = $form_title;
            $form->deleted = 0;
            $form->company_id = $company_id;

            if($this->FieldCoachingForms->save($form)){
                $this->Flash->success(__('Field Coaching Form has been saved!'));
            }else{
                $this->Flash->error(__('Something Went Wrong'));
                debug($form->errors());
            }

        }

        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Side note: do not use superglobals like `$_POST` directly, this will just cause problems, use the methods provided by [**the request object**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#request-body-data). Also do not populate entities with user data directly, [**use the patching mechanism**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html) so that it is being validated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a `existsIn` rule in the `buildRules` of `FieldCoachingModel` and a company with ID `$company_id` doesn't exist.